# Noun to refer what I understand

Tags: word-usage, nouns

Somebody mailed me something, and now I want to confirm if I understand him correctly or not. Hence, which of the following sentences is correct?

1. "To make your recent answer clear for myself, could you please confirm the following **comprehension**: Bla Bla Bla..."
2. "To make your recent answer clear for myself, could you please confirm the following **perception**: Bla Bla Bla..."

If you're going to suggest a whole new/better structure, and you think the words *comprehension* and *perception* are not good choice for my case, could you please consider to answer the following question as well:

Is there **any word** in English that I can use it to refer to "**what I got/understand**"?

Comment: I would say "... the following *understanding*".

Comment: "I would like to ensure that I have correctly understood your recent answer, so would you please confirm that the following is correct?"

Comment: 'My take on what you said is [paraphrase]. Is this what you actually mean/t?'

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is good,  but i will add my "perception" on the difference between those 2 words, "comprehension" and "perception", and also propose a few other ways you could say or mean "I understand what you just said".

Comprehension, a more long term understanding, as in "reading comprehension", to understand what new words mean, and knowing that for a long term. To comprehend something means, if I test you in a long time, you will get average marks. I don't have much to say about this, you can see I fail to understand it!

Perception, like above, but short term, like "I precise what you are telling me means {what you think, directly from what they said}". This is sounds broken to me, it is usable, but i would prefer to use "I think {something wrong/good you can point out/add}". That is a very good way to let the person know, you understand what they were talking about, YOU JUST READ THEIR MIND, Not really but still...

> This is based on what i learned growing up in B.C. and my family life.
> Reading Comprehension is used in a reference to young kids learning to read, in south west Canadian way, I assume. But if we all agree this is in reference to teaching children to read, i will shorten this.

Comment: Please provide some references or other support for your suggestions.  P.S. Your profile says you are from "Victoria Area" - is that Victoria, Canada; Australia; London; or elsewhere? This is relevant in that it affects what 'type' of English you use (e.g. British Emglish, American English, etc.).

Comment: It would be Canadian English if you want to know, and Victoria Area is where I live, but i was raised in the interior of B.C, let me know when you get this message, it is quite private!

Comment: Thanks. I see you've now included a 'half-hidden' reference in the answer - I didn't know that was possible! Thanks for the extra info, but it was really only the 'Canadian' bit that I was after. (I come from Sussex, S.England - but my brother now lives on the Sunshine Coast, having previously lived in Kelowna.) You may, of course, delete the comment, especially now that the info is in your answer.  Thanks again!